# Не правильное отображение русских букв после прочтения txt файла C#

Tags: c#, io

Разными способами читаю txt-файл, и с помощью StreamReader и с помощью команды File.ReadAllLines, всё равно вместо русских букв эти символы, англ и цифры отображаются правильно. http://prntscr.com/k38h7v

```
string[] str = new string[count];
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("База.txt"))
    {
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) //читаем по одной линии(строке) пока не вычитаем все из потока (пока не достигнем конца файла)
        {
            str[i++] = line;
        }
    }
}
spisok = new Blank[count];

for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    string[] a = str[i].Split(';');
    spisok[0].FIO = a[0];
    spisok[0].Kurs = a[1];
    spisok[0].Mesto= a[2];
    spisok[0].Vid = a[3];
    spisok[0].Nachalo = a[4];
    spisok[0].Konec = a[5];
    spisok[0].Ruk = a[6];
}
```

Сами данные из файлы

Фамилия Имя Отчество;1 к.ПИ-17;Лаб Б-2-5;Учебная;25.06.2018;07.07.2018;И.О. Фамиоия

Comment: А надо не способы перебирать, а кодировки...

Comment: советуете перебирать все кодировки?

Comment: Да. Если, конечно же, вы не можете вспомнить в какой кодировке вы этот файл записывали...

Comment: просто создал файл. И записал все с клавиатуры. Сам файл открывается и отображается правильно. Именно при чтении файла появляются символы.

Comment: Все-таки попытайтесь вспомнить какой программой вы его "просто создали".

Comment: А еще название ОС, ее версию и локализацию.

Comment: виндовс 7 64 бит. Максимальная руссифицированная. Пкм в папке Debug-создать-Текстовый документ.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте кодировку windows-1251, она же Encoding.Default

Comment: уже пробовали считать в кодировке 1251?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове конструктора класса `StreamReader` указывайте кодировку файла.

Кодировка операционной системы по умолчанию:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("База.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```